# How to find mean of a column in Python based on multiple columns with Boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset, where I need to find top 2 average rated movies for each genre. With the given layout of data, how can I achieve it? Can someone please help me understand a workaround?

In order to simplify it, I have created new columns which separates values from 'genres' into unique genres and assigned values 1 and 0 to it. So, the group by will be based on these new unique genres and not the 'genres' column. For example, if I filter on the column 'Comedy' to 1, the average rating for title 'abc', 'pqr','ghi', and 'mno' are 3.75, 2.9, 2.25, and 3.12 respectively. So, the top 2 movies based on the average rating for Comedy genre will be abc and mno. Similar logic will be followed for other unique genres.

My original dataset is very similar to the sample dataset below:

```
| movieId | title |                      genres                     | userId | rating | release_year | review_year | Children | Action | Mystery | Sci-Fi | (no genres   listed) | Drama | Fantasy | Film-Noir | Romance | Thriller | Western | Comedy | Documentary | Crime | War | Horror | Animation | IMAX | Adventure | Musical |
|:-------:|:-----:|:-----------------------------------------------:|:------:|:------:|--------------|:-----------:|:--------:|:------:|:-------:|:------:|:--------------------:|:-----:|:-------:|:---------:|:-------:|:--------:|:-------:|:------:|:-----------:|:-----:|:---:|:------:|:---------:|:----:|:---------:|:-------:|
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 3437   | 3.5    | 1995         | 2009        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 7107   | 3      | 1995         | 2014        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 17211  | 4      | 1995         | 2010        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 18056  | 3      | 1995         | 2013        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 22223  | 5      | 1995         | 2014        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 28268  | 3.5    | 1995         | 2016        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 32984  | 4.5    | 1995         | 2013        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 33260  | 0.5    | 1995         | 2014        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 35223  | 3.5    | 1995         | 2009        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 54852  | 4.5    | 1995         | 2014        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 56556  | 4      | 1995         | 2016        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 59622  | 5      | 1995         | 2017        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 78317  | 4.5    | 1995         | 2011        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 1       | abc   | Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy | 80922  | 4      | 1995         | 2005        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 1         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 2       | xyz   | Adventure__Children__Fantasy                    | 8667   | 3      | 2000         | 2010        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 2       | xyz   | Adventure__Children__Fantasy                    | 16458  | 2      | 2000         | 2005        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 2       | xyz   | Adventure__Children__Fantasy                    | 16464  | 3.5    | 2000         | 2011        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 2       | xyz   | Adventure__Children__Fantasy                    | 19786  | 4      | 2000         | 2005        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 2       | xyz   | Adventure__Children__Fantasy                    | 30494  | 3.5    | 2000         | 2005        | 1        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 1         | 0       |
| 3       | pqr   | Comedy__Romance                                 | 204961 | 4      | 2008         | 2016        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 3       | pqr   | Comedy__Romance                                 | 220587 | 3.5    | 2008         | 2016        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 3       | pqr   | Comedy__Romance                                 | 224358 | 3      | 2008         | 2014        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 3       | pqr   | Comedy__Romance                                 | 231990 | 2.5    | 2008         | 2005        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 3       | pqr   | Comedy__Romance                                 | 234484 | 3      | 2008         | 2016        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 3       | pqr   | Comedy__Romance                                 | 251794 | 1.5    | 2008         | 2011        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 4       | ghi   | Comedy__Drama__Romance                          | 4294   | 3      | 2012         | 2016        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 1     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 4       | ghi   | Comedy__Drama__Romance                          | 81593  | 2.5    | 2012         | 2009        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 1     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 4       | ghi   | Comedy__Drama__Romance                          | 114192 | 2.5    | 2012         | 2013        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 1     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 4       | ghi   | Comedy__Drama__Romance                          | 178767 | 0.5    | 2012         | 2014        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 1     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 4       | ghi   | Comedy__Drama__Romance                          | 212863 | 2      | 2012         | 2005        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 1     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 4       | ghi   | Comedy__Drama__Romance                          | 251932 | 3      | 2012         | 2005        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 1     | 0       | 0         | 1       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 5       | mno   | Comedy                                          | 16481  | 4      | 2015         | 2016        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 5       | mno   | Comedy                                          | 25066  | 4      | 2015         | 2014        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 5       | mno   | Comedy                                          | 27833  | 3      | 2015         | 2005        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
| 5       | mno   | Comedy                                          | 31864  | 1.5    | 2015         | 2014        | 0        | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0                    | 0     | 0       | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0       | 1      | 0           | 0     | 0   | 0      | 0         | 0    | 0         | 0       |
```

as dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'movieId': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5],
              'title': ['abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','pqr','pqr','pqr','pqr','pqr','pqr','ghi','ghi','ghi','ghi','ghi','ghi','mno','mno','mno','mno'],
              'genres': ['Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Animation__Children__Comedy__Fantasy','Adventure__Children__Fantasy','Adventure__Children__Fantasy','Adventure__Children__Fantasy','Adventure__Children__Fantasy','Adventure__Children__Fantasy','Comedy__Romance','Comedy__Romance','Comedy__Romance','Comedy__Romance','Comedy__Romance','Comedy__Romance','Comedy__Drama__Romance','Comedy__Drama__Romance','Comedy__Drama__Romance','Comedy__Drama__Romance','Comedy__Drama__Romance','Comedy__Drama__Romance','Comedy','Comedy','Comedy','Comedy'],
              'userId': [3437,7107,17211,18056,22223,28268,32984,33260,35223,54852,56556,59622,78317,80922,8667,16458,16464,19786,30494,204961,220587,224358,231990,234484,251794,4294,81593,114192,178767,212863,251932,16481,25066,27833,31864],
              'rating': [3.5,3.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,3.5,4.5,0.5,3.5,4.5,4.0,5.0,4.5,4.0,3.0,2.0,3.5,4.0,3.5,4.0,3.5,3.0,2.5,3.0,1.5,3.0,2.5,2.5,0.5,2.0,3.0,4.0,4.0,3.0,1.5],
              'release_year': [1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,1995,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2008,2008,2008,2008,2008,2008,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2015,2015,2015,2015],
              'review_year': [2009,2014,2010,2013,2014,2016,2013,2014,2009,2014,2016,2017,2011,2005,2010,2005,2011,2005,2005,2016,2016,2014,2005,2016,2011,2016,2009,2013,2014,2005,2005,2016,2014,2005,2014],
              'Children': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Action': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Mystery': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Sci-Fi': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              '(no genres listed)': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Drama': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
              'Fantasy': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Film-Noir': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Romance': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
              'Thriller': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Western': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Comedy': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              'Documentary': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Crime': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'War': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Horror': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Animation': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'IMAX': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Adventure': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'Musical': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

My output would be similar to the one below:

```
| Genre     | title | avg rating |
|-----------|-------|------------|
| Children  | abc   | 3.75       |
| Drama     | ghi   | 2.25       |
| Fantasy   | abc   | 3.75       |
| Fantasy   | xyz   | 3.2        |
| Romance   | pqr   | 2.9        |
| Romance   | ghi   | 2.25       |
| Comedy    | abc   | 3.75       |
| Comedy    | mno   | 3.12       |
| Animation | abc   | 3.75       |
| Adventure | abc   | 3.75       |
| Adventure | xyz   | 3.2        |
```

Please note that this is a sample dataset and there are many unique genres whose value is 0. So, such unique genres are not present in the column 'genre' of the final output. Also, some of these unique genres have only one movie falling in their category, so they have only one listing of those movies.

Comment: Try `(df.groupby('genres').mean()).head(2)`

Comment: I have edited the question for better clarity. The 'genres' column has been split into new columns to get the unique genres and the groupby will be based on these unique genres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the top 2 movies per individual genre, you first need to `melt` the dummy variables, then `groupby`+`agg`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:7], var_name='genre')
   .query('value == 1')
   .groupby(['genre', 'movieId'], as_index=False).agg({'title': 'first', 'rating': 'mean'})
   .groupby('genre').head(2)
)
```

output:

```
        genre  movieId title    rating
0   Adventure        1   abc  3.750000
1   Adventure        2   xyz  3.200000
2   Animation        1   abc  3.750000
3    Children        1   abc  3.750000
4    Children        2   xyz  3.200000
5      Comedy        1   abc  3.750000
6      Comedy        3   pqr  2.916667
9       Drama        4   ghi  2.250000
10    Fantasy        1   abc  3.750000
11    Fantasy        2   xyz  3.200000
12    Romance        3   pqr  2.916667
13    Romance        4   ghi  2.250000
```

Comment: I have updated the question for better clarity and expected output. I want to find top 2 average rated movie for each genre (By genre, I'm implying towards unique genres) The output from your code has unique genres IMAX, horror, western, film-noir, etc. which have values 0 in them, so they do not have any movies assigned to them and hence should have no presence in the output.

Comment: @hk2 I see, I updated the answer (I used the movieId as key and kept the column, in case there are several movies with the same name)

Comment: @hk2 regarding the fact that I have values for Horror, Imax, etc. this is because your data got shifted when I imported it from your question. I tried to fix it, but to remove any ambiguity, please provide the dataset as dictionary and I'll update the output ;)